# Using "SQL Native Client" (ie 2005 driver) with SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have an application that has been using the SQL Server 2005 client driver for years to connect to SQL Server 2005, 2008 and 2008 R2.

We now have SQL Server 2012 installed that 'runs fine' using that same driver but I want to ensure that there are no known problems.

I spent an hour looking at MSDN articles but could not find a clear answer on the issue that '2005 driver is supported for 2012 assuming we only want to use server features up to 2005' (as we do for now).

Has anyone else checked this out already?  Can you help point me in the right direction to find a definitive statement?

Thanks in advance, Rob C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just started testing the 2005 client + SQL Server 2014 with ODBC and OLE DB, and haven't found any issues so far. I wouldn't really recommend using compatibility levels unless you actually notice something that it fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Under your circumstances it should work fine with the driver you have in place already. However, I would "budget" for updating the driver even if you don't plan on implementing features of newer releases. SQL is good with backwards compatibility and you don't want your application falling too far behind to the point where OS support becomes an issue.

Additionally, check to make sure the compatibility level of the DB you are connecting to is in `90` (SQL 2005) or lower to be on the safe side (it probably already is) as this will ensure any updates to your database do not go beyond the SQL 2005 functionality. You can find this under the database properties in SQL Management Studio.